# What parameters does truncnorm fit return?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, distribution

When I use scipy's truncnorm fit, i.e. truncnorm.fit(my_array) I get an answer in the form of a tuple e.g.:

(1.5380758023189927, 3.6988860591528123, -0.05604604029264389, 0.03643906250110476)

I thought this would be something like min/max/mean/stddev, however none of these numbers actually correspond to anything like this for this array. I'm confused as to what exactly the truncnorm fit is giving me. Scipy documentation doesn't seem too clear on this, as for the fit method it seems to direct me to https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html which is generic for all types of distributions and doesn't detail individual ones.

Can anyone tell me what the parameters/values are for what the truncnorm fit returns?

Answer (score 1):

The `fit` method estimates the values required to parameterise the distribution, NOT statistics about the distribution. Indeed, the documentation for `rv_continuous` states:

> parameter_tuple: tuple of floats.
> Estimates for any shape parameters (if applicable), followed by those for location and scale...

The `truncnorm` distribution has two `shape` parameters, `a`, `b`. The tuple that you receive is therefore: `(fitted_a, fitted_b, fitted_loc, fitted_scale)`. These are the values needed to create a truncated normal distribution in the first place. The [`truncnorm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html) documentation is clear on what `a` and `b` are. The following demonstrates a round trip from viewing the PDF, generating random variates from that distribution, back to estimating parameters for that distribution.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import truncnorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

myclip_a = 0.5
myclip_b = 2.5
loc = 1.3
scale = 1.1
a, b = (myclip_a - loc) / scale, (myclip_b - loc) / scale

x = np.linspace(-2, 4, 100)

# create a graph of how a, b, loc, scale are used to parameterise the truncnorm PDF.
plt.plot(x, truncnorm.pdf(x, a, b, loc, scale),
         'r-', lw=5, alpha=0.6, label='truncnorm pdf')
```

[image: truncate normal pdf]

```
# create some random variates that obey that truncated normal distribution
noise = truncnorm.rvs(a, b, loc, scale, size=1000000)

# histogram the random variates to visualise the truncated normal distribution.
plt.hist(noise, bins=100);
```

[image: histogrammed truncated normal distribution]

```
# now estimate what the values of a, b, loc, scale are from the random variates
fit_a, fit_b, fit_loc, fit_scale = truncnorm.fit(noise, -1,1.2, loc=1, scale=1)

fit_myclip_a = fit_a*fit_scale + fit_loc
fit_myclip_b = fit_b*fit_scale + fit_loc

print(f"Original myclip_a: {myclip_a}, fit_myclip_a: {fit_myclip_a}")
print(f"Original myclip_b: {myclip_b}, fit_myclip_b: {fit_myclip_b}")
print(f"Original loc: {loc}, fit_loc: {fit_loc}")
print(f"Original scale: {scale}, fit_scale: {fit_scale}")
```

The output from this is:

```
Original myclip_a: 0.5, fit_myclip_a: 0.5000021691860824
Original myclip_b: 2.5, fit_myclip_b: 2.499998152872373
Original loc: 1.3, fit_loc: 1.243679897703037
Original scale: 1.1, fit_scale: 0.9391439098572698
```